# Chrome Extension: ContentScript .click not working

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

im trying to click a simple button at https://clickspeedtest.com/ but i keep getting the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined", this is my code:

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "all_frames": true,
      "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*" ],
      "js": ["content.js"],
      "run_at": "document_end"
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [ "\u003Call_urls>" ]
}
```

content.js

```
function myFunction() {
    var myEle = document.getElementsByClassName("rbutton");
    if(myEle){
        myEle.click();
    }
  
}

myFunction()
```

Comment: Why is [tag:java] here ?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will works for you. Please try this
myEle.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click'))

Comment: ty for help but says "Uncaught TypeError: myEle.dispatchEvent is not a function"